# Vendoring dependencies fails to find cryptography

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, cloud-foundry, paramiko

I am trying to deploy an app in cloud foundry which has a reference to paramiko package, which in turns references the cryptography package. I would like to deploy this with complete build isolation hence I am vendoring the dependencies and pushing to CF. However I face an issue when the python buildpack tries to pip install paramiko and it fails with an not found error for the cryptography package. This works fine if I try to install unvendored.

This is the command we use to download the packages to the vendor folder:
`pip download -r requirements.txt --no-binary :none: --dest vendor`

This is the error we face:
[image]

I see the package in question while listing out the contents of the vendor directory

[image]

Comment: can you try using `pip install --download vendor -r requirements.txt` instead? (As per [this](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/g/vcap-dev/c/0zVZCZ4tItg) discussion)

Comment: Thanks for the response @EdoAkse. The pip install --download command is deprecated (https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/3085) and the above command is the recommendation from the python buildpack docs

Comment: What is the contents of the `./vendor` directory? Can you update your answer to include that? Do you see a file in there for the package it's complaining about?

Comment: Yes @DanielMikusa I see the package in the vendor directory. I have updated my post with the screenshot.

Comment: Do you have the same python version locally that is being installed by the buildpack? The output of `cf push` should show what version of Python is being installed, compare that to `python -V` locally & make sure they are at least on the same minor version.

Comment: We use docker to contain the source and push to CF and it is using the same minor version (3.7) in both the image and CF

Comment: So we pinned down the cryptography package to a minimum of 3.0.0 (one that is needed by us at the least) and using that version we were able to vendor in our dependencies offline. I am still not sure if there are some pip version changes that are in play but I guess we are unblocked for now

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a version of `pip` at least 20.3 or higher and your buildpack in CF is probably using a version of `pip` below 20.3.  According to [this](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) documentation, only `pip` versions 20.3 and above understand `manylinux_x_y` tags, which is how your `cryptography-3.4.8-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl` file is tagged (`manylinux_2_24`).  `cryptography` has other wheels for the same version but with other tags that lower versions of `pip` will understand, but you're not downloading them because your version of `pip` understands the `manylinux_x_y` tags.

From the other wheel files shown in your screenshot, your buildpack must be using `pip` version 19.0 or higher, because it's successfully processing `bcrypt` with a `manylinux2010` tag.

To vendor the correct wheel that CF will be able to find, use the flag `--platform manylinux2010_x86_64` in your download command.  If it's using `pip` version 19.3 or higher, which it likely is, you can use the flag `--platform manylinux2014_x86_64` instead.  `cryptography` has wheels with either of those tags, both for the current version ([v35.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/35.0.0/#files)) and the version you were trying to use ([v3.4.8](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/3.4.8/#files)).

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar errors where my PCF python buildpack was unable to find some dependency whl files that I had downloaded to a vendor folder ("vendored") from a different environment. In my case, I was using a GitLab CI/CD pipeline stage which had a Docker image where I pip downloaded the files to the vendor folder.
Something like:

```html
pip download --index-url=https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@my_private_repo.com 
-r requirements.txt --no-binary=:none: -d vendor
```

Where `--index-url` specifies a private repository to grab the packages from, `--no-binary=:none:` gives pip a preference to choose wheels over source distributions, and `-d vendor` puts the wheels in a vendor directory

Even though the pip versions and python versions match between my docker image and the python buildpack. Both python 3.10.5 and pip 22.1.2 (cf python_buildpack 1.7.56). The whl downloaded by the docker image seemed to be incompatible with the python buildpack.

It produced this error after `cf push` triggered `pip install` from vendor in the python buildpack. Like one of the two errors below.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography (from versions: none)
          ERROR: No matching distribution found for cryptography
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pillow (from versions: none)
          ERROR: No matching distribution found for pillow
```

The downloaded wheels causing issues were:
cryptography-38.0.4-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl

Pillow-9.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl

I noticed that the whl files for my other dependencies were vendoring and working fine and the main difference between them and these two was these two contained `manylinux_2_28`. The other whl files seemed to have lower versions. This number refers to the glibc version the platform needs for the whl see https://peps.python.org/pep-0600/#core-definition for details.

So it seems like my docker image where I downloaded whls to the vendor folder had a newer glibc version on its linux platform than my python buildpack. As a result I specified a linux platform that seemed to be working for my other whl files when downloading these two dependencies something like:

```html
pip download --index-url==https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@my_private_repo.com 
--no-cache-dir --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 
--only-binary=:all: cryptography pillow -d vendor
```

For me this fixed the problem and I think it is because of the glibc being different between docker and the python buildpack. Because the new working whls are manylinux_2_17:

cryptography-38.0.4-cp36-abi3manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

Pillow-9.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

If you aren't quite sure if the wheel exists for a certain platform you can specify fallback platforms as shown here. I have provided their example. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/

```
python -m pip download \
   --only-binary=:all: \
   --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --platform linux_x86_64 --platform any \
   --python-version 36 \
   --implementation cp \
   --abi cp36m --abi cp36 --abi abi3 --abi none \
   SomePackage
```